# How to distinguish web sockets on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am trying to create a server with clients. Each client has a websocket and a web worker, and each worker has an own websocket to the server. 
The problem is, that i have a place on the server, where i am storing all connections

```js
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    var cid = "" + ++cid_counter;
    server.users[cid] = ws;
    ...
}
```

But now they are all storing in server.users[], and i want to store clients sockets in server.users and worker sockets in server.wokers[], but i have no idea, how to distinguish there two different types of web sockets. Maybe i could send a message, when creating a new web socket or any other solutions?

Thanks in forward

Comment: You should add auth to your socket to identify them.

Comment: Maybe you could get an advice, how to do that? or maybe any link with tutorial or smth else? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add auth to your sockets so you can identify the client.

Refer to this: [socketio-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-auth)

You can issue unique keys to clients and workers or whoever you want and then require them to emit to "authenticate" event.

You can distinguish them by having a key "type" in the db.

From npm:

**Client**:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.on('connect', function(){
  socket.emit('authentication', {username: "John", password: "secret"});
  socket.on('authenticated', function() {
    // use the socket as usual 
  });
});
```

**Server**:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

require('socketio-auth')(io, {
  authenticate: function (socket, data, callback) {
    //get credentials sent by the client 
    var key = data.key;

    db.findUser('Users', {secret: key}, function(err, user) {

      //inform the callback of auth success/failure 
      if (err || !user) return callback(new Error("User not found"));
      return callback(null, user);
    });
  }
});
```